# Why rig is not generated

Tags: rigging

I have activated riggify addon. And with armature i have scale and position all the bones. After clicking the generate option i cant find my rig but in the outliner the bones are separated with the names.
[image]

**I Can't find this rig arrow direction.**

[image]

Any help or suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the visibility of the layers in the armature panel? [image]